# Creating a service for using go modules

Tags: ubuntu, go, service

I'm trying to deploy a Go application on an Ubuntu VPS instance on DO. I need to create a service but the only examples I can find include the use of `GOPATH` like in [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@tabvn/deploy-golang-application-on-digital-ocean-server-ubuntu-16-04-b7bf5340ccd9).

Since the advent of modules I should not need to use `GOPATH` and `Go` is not installed on my server.

How can I change this code to create a service to run a Go app without `GOPATH`?

```
[Unit]
Description= instance to serve api
Requires=mysql.service
After=network.target
After=mysql.service[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
Environment=GOPATH=/srv/api/
ExecStart=/srv/api/myapp[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

edit: This file works

```
[Unit]
Description= instance to serve api
ConditionPathExists=/srv/api/myapp-api
Requires=mysql.service
After=network.target
After=mysql.service

[Service]
Type=simple
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_SYS_RAWIO
User=nobody
Group=www-data
LimitNOFILE=1024

WorkingDirectory=/srv/api
ExecStart=/srv/api/myapp-api

StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=myapp-api

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Are you planning to build the go app on this instance? Once the go app is built, GOPATH is meaningless unless the app explicitly uses it.

Comment: No, the app is built on my local dev machine and scp to the vps. Although the app is in my local GOPATH I have since converted it to use modules. Can I just remove that line and call it a day?

Comment: As I said, the binary doesn't need GOPATH unless for some reason it is explicitly checking it, which is unlikely. So, it should just work without GOPATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `GOPATH`. Just set `ExecStart` and `WorkingDirectory` (in case it makes sense).

https://fabianlee.org/2017/05/21/golang-running-a-go-binary-as-a-systemd-service-on-ubuntu-16-04/